# Run module not running

Tags: angularjs

So I have an AngularJS application in which I am attempting to bootstrap only after all of the data for the application is loaded.  I need to be able to make the requests in JSONP format so I am attempting to load the `$resource` module by using a `.run` statement.

Here's how it looks:

```
(function(){

        // Define our app
            app = angular.module("GRT", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"])

            .run(function($resource){
                console.log($resource);
            })

        // Configure our route provider and location provider
            .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
                })
                .when('/customer-site-registration', {
                    templateUrl: "views/customer-site-registration.html",
                    controller: "customerSiteRegistration"
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });

                // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            });
    }())
```

Basically no matter what I do it wont run that run block.  Any ideas?

Comment: any errors in your console?

Comment: What's a console? What's an IIFE?  Joking man, IIFE is fine, no errors in console.

Comment: If you declare your module asynchronously (when "everything is loaded") you need to bootstrap it manually like `angular.bootstrap('#element', ['GRT'])`

Comment: That's happening later in the same function.  This is just a trimmed down version for you guys to look at.

Comment: It should work, please try to reproduce a minimal scenario and check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysq3m/422/

Comment: it should work, in any case..

Answer (score 1):

Run blocks do not run until the Angular application is bootstrapped.  I needed this to run before the bootstrapping.

In this setup the `ng-app` attribute was removed from the enclosing DOM element to prevent auto-bootstrapping and I was doing it manually after running some code.

Since I was only using it to get access to resource, I instead grabbed it manually like this:

`var $resource = angular.injector(["ngResource"]).get("$resource");`

Hope this helps someone else!